# QRcode generation library for java 6 application

Tags: qr-code, java-6

I need a library for generating qrcode giving a string as input. I was using [QRgen](https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen) but it's not compatible with java 6 so i can't use it. I searched for an alternative but i found nothing. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to grab an old version of ZXing:

https://github.com/zxing/zxing/releases/tag/zxing-2.3.0

You might have to go further back, though. Since it's quite old, there was probably some version that worked with Java 6 at some point.